# What's the difference between PWM and VPW?

Tags: digital-modulation

What's the difference between pulse-width modulation (PWM) and variable pulse width (VPW)?

Comment: Where did you find the terms? (esp. VPW)?

Comment: What in the other questions concerning these terms and Wikipedia articles is missing to make this distinction?

Comment: I'd need to see the term in use, but my guess would be that VPW is PWM, but with a variable frequency.

Comment: @JarrodChristman Pretty much exactly that.

Comment: @jippie: They are two different modulations of SAE J1850 (OBD-II protocol).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word 'width' in Pulse Width Modulation is a bit misleading. PWM actually encodes an analog value as the *ratio* of High or On time ('pulse width') to the total period of a rectangular waveform.

VPW is another name for Pulse Length or Pulse Duration Modulation (PDM). It encodes an analog value in the *absolute* width of the pulse. The period between pulses is unimportant.

PDM is used in RC servos, which typically respond to a pulse width varying from 1 to 2ms. The nominal repetition frequency is 50Hz (20ms between pulses) but most servos will work between 40~70Hz - and some go up to almost 500Hz (the theoretical maximum repetition frequency of a 2ms pulse).

[image]

Comment: But [Pulse Duration Modulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse_duration_modulation) in Wikipedia redirects to PWM...

Comment: According to the Alliance for Telecommunications Industry Solutions (ATIS) PWM is deprecated and replaced by PDM, but almost everybody still calls it PWM. J1850 VPW uses a form of PDM that alternates high and low pulses (end of high pulse is start of low pulse and vice versa). J1850 PWM encodes each bit in a pulse whose width is 1/3 or 3/2 of a fixed period (similar to 'regular' PWM).

Comment: That comment explains very well what I wanted to know. But since I did a generic question, I accept your answer as-is. Thanks!